# No version information available?

Tags: package-management, libraries, suse, zypper

How can I fix this problem? What is libzypp.so.1106 and and libaugeas.so.0? Why is this error repeated so many times in libzypp.so.1106?

```
zypper: /usr/local/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by / usr/lib64/libzypp.so.1106)
zypper: /usr/local/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libzypp.so.1106)
zypper: /usr/local/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libzypp.so.1106)
zypper: /usr/local/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libzypp.so.1106)
zypper: /usr/local/lib64/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libaugeas.so.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find two copies of libxml2.so.2 in /usr/lib64 and /usr/local/lib64. I deleted and symlinked the binary and the error message is gone?